# Checkpoint_callback not working in pytorch-lighting version 1.6.3

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

With pytorch-lighting version 1.2.5 this code saved the top 1 checkpoints during training

```
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    dirpath='checkpoints',
    filename='best-checkpoint',
    save_top_k=1,
    verbose=True,
    monitor='val_loss',
    mode='min'
)

# logger = TensorBoardLogger('logs', name='btc-price')
logger = TensorBoardLogger(save_dir='lightning_logs/', name='btc-price')
early_stopping_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)
trainer = pl.Trainer(
    logger=logger,
    checkpoint_callback=checkpoint_callback,
    callbacks=[early_stopping_callback],
    max_epochs=N_EPOCHS,
    gpus=1
)
```

But the checkpoint_callback stopped working with the latest version of pytorch-lighting.

The screenshot shows an empty checkpoints folder, where previously top 1 checkpoints were successfully saved.

No exceptions are thrown while running the code.

[image]

Any idea how I can make the checkpoint_callback work in the latest pytorch-lighting version?

Comment: Google Colab has sometimes the issue that files don't show up immediately. Try to refresh the contents manually. And note: In newer versions the checkpoint_callback Trainer argument got deprecated. Please pass the model checkpoint callback directly to the list of callbacks like you did for early stopping.